# Sql to remove a substring within a string (oracle 11g)

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g, regexp-replace

I have a sample string below.

```
"MHV9DRDUY7 Confirmed.on 31/8/18 at 10:18 AMKsh9,500.00 received from 25470000000 JAMES BOND.New Account balance is Ksh12,050,100"
```

I would like to remove the substring `"New Account balance is Ksh12,050,100"` from the main string using SQL.

Please note that the amount in the substring (`Ksh12,050,100`) is not fixed, hence I am having a challenge using `REGEXP_REPLACE`.

Comment: What problem are you having using `REGEXP_REPLACE()`? Any regexp tutorial will explain how to match a sequence of characters that isn't fixed.

Comment: Is the part to remove always in the end of the string?

Comment: have you tried using replace(field, 'New Account balance is ([A-Za-z0-9,]*)','')?

Comment: @Aleksej yes, it always at the end of the string.

Comment: @Gowdhaman008 used.
REGEXP_REPLACE (field,'New Account balance is (Ksh[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)(.[0-9]+)*)','')

Thanks for the heads up. Worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the substring to remove always is in the final part of the string, and that the substring `'New Account balance is Ksh'` at most occurs once in the string, you don't need regular expressions.

You can find the position where the string to remove starts (by `INSTR`) and then trim the string up to that position (`SUBSTR`):

```
select substr(yourString, 1, instr(yourString, 'New Account balance is Ksh') -1)
from ...
```